# Why in PhpStorm / vue/cli app CTRL+click on some variable shows multiple implementation?

Tags: phpstorm

In vue file of my @vue/cli 4.0.5 with PhpStorm 2019.2.5 when I CTRL+click on some variable
I see that this variable has multiple implementation : https://prnt.sc/v6erk6

But this file and all my project has only one javascript current_tasks_total_count variable
and clicking on both dropdown options of the printscreen above the same
variable definition of my vue file is opened : https://prnt.sc/v6f65v

I excluded public from the project : https://prnt.sc/v6f41w
I used this options in similar cases with css classes defined.

Are there sme options for this issue ?

Comment: Does it only happen with this variable, or with others as well? does the issue persist after caches invalidation (**File > Invalidate caches, Invalidate and restart**)?

Comment: The same issue for all variables.  I tried the command you wrote and it did not help

Comment: works fine for me. Can you repeat the issue in a new Vue cli project?

Comment: Looks like in new app I have no this problem. Is it some misconfig of my app ? Can it be cleared somehow?

Comment: no idea, sorry:( do you have any symlinks in your project?

Comment: any symlinks ? Not sure. seems not.What is it?